# RazorComponent SelectList in _Layout. Bad idea?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have a ASP.NET Core webapp using razor pages. I would like to create a dropdown present on all pages to choose a project. Ideally this would populate from a table within the DbContext. The table in question contains several fields, the two important ones are Id (PK) and the Name. I would then like to somehow store the user's project selection and have all the index pages look to that value when populating the index. It would have to look to the Id value but I would like the dropdown to display the Name.

I am a total newbie and I'm looking for guidance on how to do that. I think that a RazorComponent makes sense though I am not sure at all.

I have got the filtering working on a single index basis but I am struggling with trying to get that functionality app-wide.

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Razor Pages, I believe you can use [ViewComponents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for that.

View Components are completely self-contained objects that render HTML for Razor views, and gives you a lot of control.

You could inject a service into a view component like this:

```
public class ProjectsViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ProjectService projectService;

    public ProjectsViewComponent(ProjectService projectService)
    {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View("default", projectService.GetProjects());
    }
}
```

And then have the View Component forward the projects to an component

```
@model IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
<h3>Users</h3>
<form>
    <ll>
        <select class="form-control" asp-items="Model" multiple="true"></select>
    </ll>
    <button type="submit" asp-page="WhateverPageNeedToHandleIt">Update</button>
</form>
```

Then the final step is just calling it in your _layout.cs

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Projects")
</div>
```

You can also convert a list to select item list from your projectService class like this:

```
return projects.ConvertAll(p =>
            {
                return new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = p.ToString(),
                    Value = p.ToString(),
                    Selected = false
                };
            });
```

A good tutorial can be found here.
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components

Comment: Thats fantastic, thanks very much! This all looks good and makes sense. With the "WhateverPageNeedToHandleIt" page, I guess I will somehow load it into the session. I know thats possible but thats what I'll learn next! Thanks again!